# Bash script pass ssh command to remote server and bring back the prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, restart

I am restarting bunch of remote servers via bash script but the script waits for me to break before moving on.

```
#!/bin/bash
main()
{
        hostlist=("server1" "server2")
        echo -e "----- Reatsrting all servers -----"
        for host in ${hostlist[@]};
        do
                echo "----- Restarting $host -----"
                ssh -t $host "sudo reboot -f now"
                echo "----- Restart of $host complete -----"
        done
        echo "----- All servers restarted -----"
}
main
```

The result of above script is

```
----- Reatsrting all servers -----
----- Restarting server1 -----
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.10.1.11 port 22: Broken pipe
----- Restart of server1 complete -----
----- Restarting server2 -----
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.10.1.12 port 22: Broken pipe
----- Restart of server2 complete -----
----- All servers restarted -----
```

If you notice the "**packet_write_wait: Connection to ...**", this happens as the server takes time to restart and i have to manually break it by hitting enter, when i do that i get the packet_write_wait line and the script moves on with next code.

Is there a way by which i can just shoot the restart command and forget so i can move on with the rest of the script (get my prompt back without manually intervening)?

Comment: did you try `ssh -t $host 'sudo reboot -f now & exit'` ?

Comment: this works. thanks. So i just had to pass exit along. so simple and effective. thanks @Fravadona

Comment: simply adding `&` will do the trick. `exit` is implicit since there are no more commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it all together, with the advice from comments.

```
#!/bin/bash
main()
{
        hostlist=("server1" "server2")
        echo -e "----- Reatsrting all servers -----"
        for host in ${hostlist[@]};
        do
                echo "----- Restarting $host -----"
                ssh -t $host 'sudo reboot -f now &'
                echo "----- Restart of $host complete -----"
        done
        echo "----- All servers restarted -----"
}
main
```